# Printing Raster extents but not showing on console

Tags: arcpy, extents

```
print("Data {0}, xmin{1}, ymin{2}, xmax{3}, ymax{4}".format(ext.Xmin, ext.Xmax, ext.Ymin, ext.Ymax))
```

The line of code above is not printing out the extent for each raster in my dataset in the code below. It runs without an error, but nothing is displayed.

```
myRasterList = []
for RAWR in myRasterList:
    ext = arcpy.Describe(RAWR).Extent
    print(ext.Xmin)
    print ("Data extents {4}, Xmin{0}, Xmax{1}, Ymin{2}, Ymax{3}".format(ext.XMin, ext.XMax, ext.YMin, ext.YMax, RAWR))
```

```
import arcpy, sys, os
env = arcpy.env
from arcpy import management as DM
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import analysis as AN
from arcpy import conversion as CV

env.workspace = r"F:/Fall 2019/GEOG 625/Exam Data/ExamData/MichaelBreidert/Pen/HMB.gdb"

scriptdir = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
#ws = arcpy.env.workspace = r"F:\Fall 2019\GEOG 625\Exam Data\ExamData\MichaelBreidert"
# creating variable to hold GDB
hmb = scriptdir + "/HMB.gdb"

myRasterList = []
for RAWR in myRasterList:
    ext = arcpy.Describe(RAWR).Extent
    print("Data {0}, xmin{1}, ymin{2}, xmax{3}, ymax{4}".format(ext.Xmin, ext.Xmax, ext.Ymin, ext.Ymax))
```

How do I print the extents of all data in my HMB.gdb?

Comment: print("Data {0}, xmin{1}, ymin{2}, xmax{3}, ymax{4}".format(ext.Xmin, ext.Xmax, ext.Ymin, ext.Ymax))

This line of code is not printing out the extent for each raster in my dataset. It runs without an error, but no display

Comment: Done, is there more to be needed or should I repost with proper instructions?

Comment: print (arcpy.ListRasters())

for RAWR in arcpy.ListRasters():
    ext = arcpy.Describe(RAWR).extent
    print ("~~~~~~~~~~~\n~~~~~~~~~~~")
    print (RAWR)
    print ("Xmin{0}, Xmax{1}, ".format(ext.XMin, ext.XMax,))
    print ("Ymin{0}, Ymax{1}".format(ext.YMin, ext.YMax))

Answer (score 2):

Nothing prints because your code never gets to the `print()` function. 
Right before the `for` loop, you explicitly set `myRasterList = []` i.e. an empty list, so there's nothing to loop through.

You need to fill `myRasterList` using the `arcpy.ListRasters()` function.

You also need to be careful with your (lower and upper) case.

For example (slightly abbreviated from your code above):

```
import arcpy, sys, os
env = arcpy.env

env.workspace = r"F:/Fall 2019/GEOG 625/Exam Data/ExamData/MichaelBreidert/Pen/HMB.gdb"

myRasterList = arcpy.ListRasters()  # list every raster in env.workspace, 
                                    # i.e. r"F:/Fall 2019/GEOG 625/Exam Data/ExamData/MichaelBreidert/Pen/HMB.gdb"
for RAWR in myRasterList:
    ext = arcpy.Describe(RAWR).extent  # note lower case "extent"
    # note case of "XMin" (not "Xmin") etc.
    print("Data {0}, xmin{1}, ymin{2}, xmax{3}, ymax{4}".format(ext.XMin, ext.XMax, ext.YMin, ext.YMax))
```